# Block copy PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I would like block copy (ctrl+c ctrl+v) PDF document using java. I have a code that build a PDF document with JasperReport...

```
//seta o caminho dos arquivos jasper
        String pathLote = ScopeSupport.getServletContext().getRealPath("priv/sgc/relatorios/AtaPregaoLotePageReport.jasper");
        String pathCabecalho = ScopeSupport.getServletContext().getRealPath("priv/sgc/relatorios/CabecalhoPageReport.jasper");
        String pathRodape = ScopeSupport.getServletContext().getRealPath("priv/sgc/relatorios/rodapePageReport.jasper");
        String imagemDir = ScopeSupport.getServletContext().getRealPath("/priv/comum/img");

        //HashMap parametros passa o parametro usado na query e o caminho da imagem
        HashMap<String,Object> parametros = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        parametros.put("idPregao", idPregao);
        parametros.put("idLote", idLote);
        parametros.put("IMAGEM_DIR", imagemDir + "/");
        parametros.put("USUARIO", "NomeUsuario" );
        parametros.put("texto", texto);
        parametros.put("numeroAta", numAta);

        if(numAta != null && numAta > 0)
            parametros.put("relatorio", "Ata "+numAta);

        HashMap<String,Object> parametrosSub = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        parametrosSub.put("CabecalhoPageReport", pathCabecalho);
        parametrosSub.put("rodapePageReport", pathRodape);
        parametrosSub.put("AtaPregaoPorLotePageReport", pathLote);

        for(String element : parametrosSub.keySet()){
            parametros.put(element, (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject((String) (parametrosSub.get(element))));
        }

        JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject( pathLote );
        JasperPrint printRel = JasperFillManager.fillReport( report, parametros, getJDBCConnection() );
        byte[] bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(printRel);

        httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+ report.getName() + ".pdf" +"\";");
        httpResponse.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        httpResponse.setContentType("application/pdf");

        ServletOutputStream ouputStream = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
        ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        ouputStream.flush();
        ouputStream.close();
```

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try out this when you use jasper report 5.6.x

```
  SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
  configuration.setEncrypted(true);
  configuration.set128BitKey(true);
  configuration.setUserPassword("jasper");
  configuration.setOwnerPassword("reports");
  configuration.setPermissions(PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING); //PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY is no set
  exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
  //extrac of http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/pdfencrypt/index.html
```

In legacy version you can use `JRExporterParameter`

```
  pdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
  //when you want copy files use 
  //pdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY);

  pdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_ENCRYPTED, true);
        pdfExporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.USER_PASSWORD, ".sigaAr4gos@");
```

Note: `JRPdfExporterParameter` is deprecade

Answer (score -1):

Probably I am wrong but I strongly believe that it is impossible. You are building PDF document and reviewing it with PDF Reader. The ability to copy parts of the document is the functionality of reader, so you cannot control this on document building phase. PDF is not HTML where you can handle events yourself and therefore block some of them.

I will be glad to know that I am wrong...